# TypeScript — How to infer key-value type based on dynamic key

Tags: typescript, use-reducer

Suppose I had a state object with an interface such as this:

```
interface IState {
    car_brand: string;
    year: number;
    + many other properties with various types
}
```

and I wanted to produce a reducer function for changing values in this state. I’d be tempted to have a single `action` called `set_value` that could handle changing any of the values in state. I would then type that action like this:

```
enum ACTION_TYPE {
    set_value = ‘set_value’,
}

type IAction =
     {
          type: ACTION_TYPE.set_value;
          payload: { ??? };
      };
```

Now my question is how could I type `payload` so that it can handle any key from IState and then correctly infer the required type of the value? In pseudo-code, I’d be looking for something like this:

```
payload: { `a key from IState`: `a value whose type matches the particular key chosen from IState` }
```

How can I write that payload type correctly in TypeScript?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGUx0sg3gWAChkTkE4oB9AIyjhABMAuZAZzClAHMBuI05AE8IFFiACuAW2rQ+hAL5EiECZOQBBAMIAVVAHkAcpW0BNAAoBRPP1KsIYSgDc4AG3EoAvMgDkdh87cIbwAaIkVCIjBBAAcUVHUEMGAAexAAHm1kCAAPSEZWZABrCEFkmDRMbAgAPmQPG1ICYgEWqNiWLV1DY3MLADo-J1d3ORaW6LhBF2S4ZmtmsbHiwRZtUIXFgQD3FgwsSABtbQBddc2SeVGWy6VCGHEQRJSQZBgMrNyVBgLlsor9moACnYVV2lUgwWQiCSqV2CRh6W01QAlCxHMlgAx5gIQYdoc8+hMpjMGH1lsc6lCnqlCZNprM+tsIHJwkQYICGnh5FCCnsqmdGm0IB0dPojKZLAN7ENApCifS5rhlixvMIKCFkEyWAAmeThZE8IA
?

Answer (score 2):

I'd use the Typescript utility type [Partial](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype)

Like this:

```js
type IAction =
{
    type: ACTION_TYPE.set_value;
    payload: Partial<IState>
};
```

This means that `payload` has the same type of `IState`, but with all the properties converted to optional.

That way this works, and correctly constrains the type of `year` to be a `number`:

```
interface IState 
{
    car_brand: string;
    year: number;
}

{
   type: ACTION_TYPE.set_value,
   payload: {
      year: 1997 // Would produce an error if you changed it to a string
   }
}
```

But this results in an error because `foo` doesn't exist on your state type:

```js
interface IState 
{
    car_brand: string;
    year: number;
}

{
   type: ACTION_TYPE.set_value,
   payload: {
      foo: "baz"
   }
}
```